# how to make a pattern with loops in java

Tags: java, loops

```
public class NestedLoopPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int HASHTAG_AMMOUNT = 6;

        for (int i=0; i < HASHTAG_AMMOUNT; i++) {
            System.out.println("#");
            for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("#");
        }
    }
}
```

I am supposed to make this pattern with nested loops, however with the code above I can't,

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```

I just keep getting this as my output:

```
#
#
#
 #
#
  #
#
    #
#
      #
#
         #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You erroneously were calling `System.out.println()` for the first hash mark, which was printing a newline where you don't want it.  Just change that call to `System.out.print()` and you should be good to go:

```
 public class NestedLoopPattern {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         final int HASHTAG_AMMOUNT = 6;

         for (int i=0; i < HASHTAG_AMMOUNT; i++) {
             // don't print a newline here, just print a hash
             System.out.print("#");
             for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
             System.out.println("#");
         }
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```

Answer (score 0):

[java8](/questions/tagged/java8) solution:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MAX)
                .forEach(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i + 1)
                        .mapToObj(j -> j == i + 1 ? "#\n" : j == 1 ? "# " : "  ")
                        .forEach(System.out::print)
                );
```